# Building in release mode in Visual Studio is extremely slow to startup

Tags: visual-studio, performance, build, release

I have a small solution with about 20 C# projects.  A debug build takes about 10 seconds.  However, a release build takes 1 minute 10 seconds.  During the first minute of the release build Visual Studio is unresponsive and appears to do nothing.  There is no CPU activity, only a small amount of disk activity, and no compiler output appears.  I might suspect a project custom pre-build step, but it doesn't even get to that point.  Once it starts to compile projects and I see build output, everything proceeds at normal speed - just as with debug.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: A debug build at 1 minute is already unusually long for 20 projects.  Try it on another machine.

Comment: I don't know about the slow startup but release builds generally take longer because they are optimizing code.

Comment: You are correct..1 minute is long.  I was rounding up.  The actual debug build time was 10 seconds.  And I don't think optimization is a factor as compilation hasn't even started.